# Running VBA script causes excel to stop responding

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that adds sheets to around 500 excel files.
I had no problems running the VBA script and adding simple sheets, but when I try to add a sheet with VBA script in it and graphs and buttons, it works for a while and than freezes.

Here is the code. I know it does not have error handling - any suggestions how to tackle this problem or maybe what is causing excel to freeze?

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()

Const ForReading = 1
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject

Dim txtStream As TextStream

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, folder As Scripting.folder, file As Scripting.file, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim directory As String

'The path for the equipement list. - add the desired path for all equipement or desired value stream only.
Set txtStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile("O:\SiteServices\Maintenance\Maintenance Support Folder\Maintenance Department Information\HTML for Knowledgebase\Excel for Knowledgebase\Equipement paths-all.txt", ForReading)

Do Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = txtStream.ReadLine
    If strNextLine <> "" Then

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(strNextLine)


    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open strNextLine & Application.PathSeparator & file.Name

        Set wb = Workbooks("Equipment Further Documentation List.xls")
    For Each sh In Workbooks("Master File.xls").Worksheets
        sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Next sh

     ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
     ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

        End If


    Next file
    End If

    Loop
txtStream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Add as a first line to your sub: `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and add the other line right before `End Sub` : `Application.ScreenUpdating = true`

Comment: where does the crash occur? (which line etc)

Comment: I do not have a chance to check where does it crush... It will add the sheet to the first 4 or 5 files and then crash without a chance to check where did it fail...

Comment: Is there anything in the sheets that you are copying that may be triggering automatically? If yes, please can you also post the VBA in the sheets that you are copying.

Comment: no nothing there there are two macros that are triggered by a button - one to send a graph by email and one to print it out.

Comment: @KazJaw - did added the lines, and run the code and still the same thing...

Comment: I think it's not crashing but it freezes as your sub is time-consuming. Try all three suggestions from my answer and give feedback if anything changed.

Comment: @Saint Why can't you see which line is causing the crash? Is it a complete excel crash or just a code error (e.g. message box pops up saying error)? One issue I can see is that you assume that any xls file in each of the folders is called "Equipment Further Documentation List.xls"

Comment: @saint KazJaw makes a good point. At the end of each loop add in "DoEvents" line, then try again. This command pauses execution very briefly while the Application processes events and so on and should stop it hanging. You can also add "Application.StatusBar = "Processed " & strNextLine" as a line, this will let you know how far through it is

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you can use the `GetExtensionName` method instead of `Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls"`. If you wanted to, you can change this to `FSO.GetExtensionName(file.Name) = "xls"`. Just a little cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @KazJaw - I am not assuming, all the files are called "Equipment Further Documentation List.xls" - this might be the problem that the macro runs faster than the file is closed and before the current file is closed the next file is opened...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem...

The solution was to add a line of code:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

after the line:

```
sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```

which allowed time to copy the sheet to the new excel file.

So far it has been working like a charm.

I want to thank everyone that helped me with this issue.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

So, some tips for you:

**1st. (according to comment)**

Add as a first line to your sub: `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and add the other line right before `End Sub` : `Application.ScreenUpdating = true`

**2nd. Move this line (it's setting constance reference):**

```
Set wb = Workbooks("Equipment Further Documentation List.xls")
```

before:

```
Do Until txtStream.AtEndOfStream
```

**3rd is just a tip.**

To see the progress of your sub add the following line:

```
Application.StatusBar = file.Name
```

after this line:

```
Workbooks.Open strNextLine & Application.PathSeparator & file.Name
```

Before the `End Sub` add additionally this code:

```
Application.StatusBar = false
```

As a result you can see in Excel app, in the status bar, file name which is currently in process.

**Keep in mind that working with 500 files must be time-consuming.**

Comment: 3rd point is important- it'll give you idea if your sub is running.

Comment: also, add in DoEvents before each loop. This will ensure excel continues to refresh and remain somewhat responsive.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey - will try this out later on... and give you a shout what is happening... Thanks

Comment: @Saint, is this sub running? can you see file names changing in statusbar?

Comment: @KazJaw - Yep it is running... But same thing happens, after 4 files the macro freezes and I have to reset the PC to close the excel, not even in the task manager I can close it.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey - Adding DoEvent did not help either still freezes, but at least I can close the Developer and restart the excel without restarting the PC... Thanks

Comment: Sometimes I have the same situation when I run complicated macro. In my opinion your macro is still running even excel is freezing. Check how much time you need to process all 4 files and than calculate expected total time. Alternatively- try to run it for only 10 files- give it time to see that sub will finish.

Comment: @Saint, alternatively, to prove it's working you can add `Stop` after `Application.StatusBar = file.Name`. Process will stop for each file which will require pressing F5 to run it further but again, you will be able to check that it's running...

Comment: @KazJaw - the macro is not running when excel freezes, I checked if the sheets are being added to the excel files and unfortunately not. I will try a shorter list of 10 or so and the Stop method...

Comment: @KazJaw Tried the stop method and still the same... added the sheet to 3 files and macro froze again... I will try to rewrite the macro, or try to run it of a different PC, or something

Comment: can it be caused by running the macro off a networked drive??

Comment: it would be strange that loop goes four times and then stop. I would additionally check the file which is the last open (i.e. 4th one?) if there is everything ok with it. if you can open it manually, etc.

Comment: The file is ok I can open it ok - all the files are generally the same with some information on them differ...

Comment: Tried to run it of a local HDD instead a networked one and still the same...I think it is all happening because it is friday... :P

Comment: I have managed to debug the code and the error that is causing excel to freeze is: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Copy' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: do you know what to with that?

Comment: If the destination workbook already contains something like a table with the same name then this will fail. Try using worksheet.Move. It is a bit more reliable (though it will still fail with the table example). You can always then close the source workbook without saving and repoen it again.

Comment: 1st. there are some limitation of sheets within one workbook.

Comment: Are you able to work with the XLSX format instead? It has fewer limitations.

Comment: 2nd. is your loop set correctly? `For Each sh In Workbooks("Master File.xls").Worksheets` >> `sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)` >> `Next sh` seems to copy all the same all the time between two the same workbooks. Isn't it?

Comment: @KazJaw - all the 500 excel files have the same name... and I am adding one sheet to the one by one - so kind of I am copying the same thing between two files all over and over again... They are in different folders

Comment: @Cor_Blimey - I can not work with .xlsx unfortunately... I can try but I would have to overwrite the 500 files and save them as .xlsx format - doable but time consuming...