# Replace cell value to contain percentage of total in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet containing entities, their characteristics, a value for the characteristic and a total as follows:

```
Entity  CHAR1   CHAR2   CHAR3   CHAR4   Total
1       10      20      5       5       40
2       5       100     30      25      160
3       25      25      10      20      80
```

Now I want to replace the values with percentages in which the total column is seen as 100% for each row seperately.
This would in this example result in:

```
Entity  CHAR1   CHAR2   CHAR3   CHAR4
1       25      50      12,5    12,5
2       3,125   62,5    18,75   15,625
3       31,25   31,25   12,5    25
```

As my data-set is pretty big i'm wondering if there is a fast solution to do this? I get stuck because placing a formula in each cell will require calculating the new value using the old value in the cell itself. And using a new worksheet might give me some performance issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the sum of the values in the column is used as the "100%" and each value should be calculated as a percentage of that total value?

Comment: Yes so the percentage is on a per row basis. So the total of each row in the new table would result in 100%

Comment: *"And using a new worksheet might give me some performance issues"*: why do you think this? Have you tried it?

Comment: Because i'm already close to the max number of lines excel supports. So opening a second worksheet with as many rows will definitely exceed the limit.

Comment: How many lines & columns you currently use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this sub and all should work as you asked (note that you need to define the TotalColumn column number (since it isn't evident in the example)

```
Sub MakePercent()
     Dim Cell As Range, CalcRange As Range, TotalColumn As Variant
     TotalColumn = 'Write the column number or letter here 
     Set CalcRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,2), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,TotalColumn - 1))
     For Each Cell In CalcRange
         Cell.Value = CDbl(Cell.Value) / CDbl(ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,totalColumn))
     Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a fun fact. If you change `TotalColumn` to a variant then you'll be able to pass a number or letter into the Cells column parameter.

Comment: With a few edits this worked, thanks!
Edits:
-You miss a *100 in the cell value calculation
-And you miss a closing bracket in the set CalcRange line.

Comment: Oh and nice addition Thomas! I was looking for this because counting the columns is not an easy job with hundreds of them

Comment: @OutOfTheBox glad it helped.  I fixed the code here to add the bracket, but the multiplication by 100 was left out intentionally in case the cells were formatted as percentages by you after the fact (as this would then multiply the values by a subsequent 100).  Either way works of course

Answer (score 1):

Minor update from myself:

The macro as provided by RGA worked fine, until I expanded my data with some extra columns. It then caused excel to freeze and therefore i went looking for a new solution.

If found the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144312/running-vba-script-causes-excel-to-stop-responding) and adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` to the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` to the end of the macro resolved the freezing issue.

This leads to the following code:

```
Sub MakePercent()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Dim Cell As Range, CalcRange As Range, TotalColumn As Variant
     TotalColumn = 'Write the column number or letter here 
     Set CalcRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,2), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,TotalColumn - 1))
     For Each Cell In CalcRange
         Cell.Value = CDbl(Cell.Value) / CDbl(ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,totalColumn))
     Next Cell

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```